# How to manage links in an automatic way?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

In my project's homepage there must be some images, these must link to other pages. Now, I want to manage these links in an automatic way using `PHP`. The only idea I came up with is to make a form and insert the images into some buttons and make their background invisible.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>FRESH ALBUMS</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="myline"></div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="contentimg/abbeyroad.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
        <div class="caption">
            <h4>Beatles</h4>
        </div>
        <p> test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">TEST2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">TEST3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">TEST4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the `HTML` at the moment. I just want to know if there are better ideas, options and if it will stay responsive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell us, what is your expected result. "Managed in an automatic way" doesn't say much about what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I want a script php to do the queries and to display the result If you click on one of these images.

Comment: What queries, what result. I think you should read this how-to before you ask question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand exactly what you are asking, but I cannot leave comments so I will try to answer what I think you are asking.

For the `HTML` part, you don't need a form with buttons, you can make hyperlinks out of the images instead, and the `PHP` can get the images to match the hyperlinks when it sends the page to your users browser. The `PHP` code would look like:
echo "

```
<a href='".$newPageLink."'>
    <img src='".$imageLocation."' width='100px' height='100px'>
</a>";
```

Where `$newPageLink` is a variable in your `PHP` script that holds the path information for your hyperlink, and `$imageLocation` is the path information for where the image is stored.

All you need is a `foreach` or `while` loop to go through all of the images that you want on the page and also all of the pages that each image should link to. If it is always a manageable and unchanging list, you could store the values in an `array` in your script. For larger lists, or lists that are dynamic/always changing you might need to use a `MySQL` database table to store the image and hyperlink information.